# NAT64 option not available on mac

Tags: macos, ethernet, ipv6

I have been trying to setup a NAT64 network on mac. My config is -

1. I am using USB to Ethernet adaptor on my Macbook air.
2. I am connected to a network that has only ipv4 setup (according to my best guess).
3. Running a Mac osx Yosemite 10.10.5

I have tried everything in instructions. Clicked on network sharing while pressing option key. Still the nat64 option is not visible.

I have tried the same with USB tethering as network source.

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Late answer, but anyway... 
NAT64-style Internet sharing is only available on 10.11 and newer. See [Apple KB on the subject](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html)